# Difference between printf and ESP_LOGI?

Tags: c, esp-idf

I just want to know, what is the difference between esp's `ESP_LOGx` and `printf`, related to memory use and its other features.
And which is the best to use for log `ESP_LOGI`, `printf` or any other logging function?

Comment: what did you learn yourself? What do you know about those families of functions/macros?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that for most of ad hoc debuging this it is a matter of preference with indication to use printf.

ESP_LOG(I/W/E) are intended to implement "permanent" logging functionality in the code and is also used in the ESP-IDF itself. Then depending on debugging scenario it is possible to globally or locally enable required verbosity levels of information to receive.

Comment: what about the stack size used? Does both uses the same

Comment: In stack size ESP_LOGx will take more space.

Answer (score 1):

Dont use printf, use ESP_LOGI/E/W. There are several advantages, for example color coded messages.
[image]

Comment: Curious, how do you get these to color code? I see nothing in the documentation on that.

Comment: I dont know if you can configure it or change defaults

Comment: I figured it out. You need this build flag:
build_flags = -D CONFIG_ARDUHAL_LOG_COLORS=1 
; Sets the ESP32 core to output LOG messages with color codes

Comment: @CodeGrue may be a little more in detail might help others who land on this question.